# Angular UI Grid: How do I make a second ui grid visible from a button in the first ui grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, grid, cell

Okay, I made this [**example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/KMlxQewFT5K3zNB7RA8n?p=preview) to show you guys the code that I am working with.

I am trying to click one of the buttons( called "Grid") in the first UI Grid table under the column "Company". Once you click the button, I want it to display the 2nd UI Grid.

```
cellTemplate:'<button type="button"  ng-click="hideGrid = !hideGrid">' + 'Grid' + '</button>' }
```

I think this line has to be changed to make it link with the 2nd ui grid.

It would be tremendous help if somebody could help or guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close.  This is because your grid doesn't have access to your app's scope when called like that.  You need `grid.appScope`.

`ng-click="grid.appScope.hideGrid = !grid.appScope.hideGrid"`

Working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ldCnNsqOZCrQs6WtZtOM?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate the quick and helpful response. Another question if you dont mind, how do you make only one of cells with a button rather than all 3?

Comment: You need to use ng-if.